# Gzip compression or Mod_deflate not working

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, wordpress, google

Our wordpress website we need to enable gzip compression we followed below instruction to enabled.

1. we have wp rocket plugin this plugin automatically added compression mode_deflate lines in .htaccess
2. We try to enable from server side so we followed this below article instruction to enable gzip compression

(https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/how-to-configure-mod_deflate-for-apache-on-centos-7/)

In this article given edit file sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_deflate.conf and paste the below code

```
 <filesMatch ".(js|html|txt)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
    DeflateCompressionLevel 7 
    DeflateMemLevel 8 
    DeflateWindowSize 10
```

we try to do this step we can't save the file when we try to saving file its show 'NO SUCH FILE DIRECTORY'.

and also we tried to edit this file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. This file also can't to save.

Why don't I have a httpd directory?

How to enable Gzip compression ?